# Solar Distillation

Tags: solar-cells

I have a rather large project on the northern beaches of Tanzania and am looking for the optimum off grid method to distill water. We have a salty well. I have seen many many diagrams on the web on the subject with some of them being very close to suiting my purpose. So far I have not seen anything produce more than 10 litres/square meter of glass coverage per day. If I could make a coverage of 10 sq mt and get 100 litres per day it may suffice. 
My question is this. If I can continually boil water in a reservoir and distill the steam is it more efficient that merely heating from the sun. I would have thought so.
My thoughts are steering toward using the already discovered and mass produced solar hot water system that you see on many a suburban roof.
If I was to block the outlet and reduce the psi on pressure relief valve and tap the steam from that exit would it be more efficient than the standard sloping glass model we all know? If I was to add another row of evacuated tubes would it help? Has anyone come across any research on this subject? Cheers
Mike

Comment: This sounds like it might be a better fit on Engineering.SE or diy.SE.

Comment: I think you mean you don't know.

Comment: I don't know, but that's not what I mean. I mean that this sounds like an engineering question, not a physics question, and it seems like several high-level users agree.